Would a question about standards related to finance be on topic?
Specifically, I have a question about the ISO 10383 standard (market identification codes), and when I started to ask, I realized that I couldn't find any tags that really fit the question (well, there was one).
That said, are questions related to standards that are heavily used in finance (I'm using this, for example, to populate a listed global security master) on-topic on Quantitative Finance?

I think it'll be alright. Our biggest rule of thumb is simply, "would a professional quant ask this". So a lot of questions that aren't necessarily quantitative in nature are ok here if the topic concerns quants.

Not all finance questions having to do with data would necessarily be on topic.  It would only be acceptable if relevant to an actual practicing professional quant.  It is not sufficient for the question to be relevant to a programmer working in finance.
I may be wrong, but I have never heard of a quant messing with ISO standard codes.  That is something usually reserved for the developers and technologists, and this forum is aspiring to a more front-office user base.
Having said that, the worst that could happen is you post, it gets down-voted, and we move on.
